# Reference-type return functions and postfix increment

Tags: c++, reference, post-increment

I am reading [the Wikipedia page about references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29).

It contains the following code:

```
int& preinc(int& x) 
{ 
    return ++x;  // "return x++;" would have been wrong
}

preinc(y) = 5; // same as ++y, y = 5
```

I did try to compile using `return x++;` instead of `return ++x;`. As predicted, this led to the following error:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’
>   from a temporary of type ‘int’

I don't understand this error. I have the vague intuition that the incrementation of x happens too late (i.e., after the function call of preinc is over). However, I don't see how this is a problem since the variable x never ceases to exist. Any explanation is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of the error is that post increment `x++` returns a temporary value, and this cannot be bound to a non-const lvalue reference. This is a simplified version of the same problem:

```
int i = 42;
int& j = i++; // Error: i++ returns temporary value, then increments i.
const int& k = i++; // OK, const reference can bind to temporary.
```

Comment: Related: `i = i++` is UB in C++11, but `i = ++i` isn't (amymore).

Answer (score 0):

The preincrement (`++i`) does the increment and then return a reference to the variable (Wich have been modified). Postincrement (i++) computes the result of the increment, stores it in a temp local variable, and return a copy of that result after it does the increment. This is done to make look that the increment is done after the call:

```
int operator++(int)
{
   int tmp( *this );
   ++(*this);
   return tmp;
}
```

***This code is for learning purposes, is not real code (int is not a class). Is for showing how postincrement works.***

So, as you can see, `i++` returns a copy, not a reference. So you cannot initialize the return value, because its a rvalue, not a reference to an existing variable.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to increment x before returning it and see if it solves the problem

```
int& preinc(int& x) 
{ 
    x++;
    return x;  // "return x++;" would have been wrong

}
```